# Código de comparación de datos no funciona, ni da error

Tags: c#

Quiero que me valide los datos que ingreso en un cuadro de texto. Si mi búsqueda me llena el campo existencia (`txtexitencia`), que me compare con el campo venta (`txtcantidadvendida`), y si `venta > existencia`, que me dispare un error, o de lo contrario que continúe.

El código es el siguiente, cuyo problema es que aparentemente no hace nada:

```
private void txtcantidadvendida_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double existencia, venta;
    double.TryParse(txtexistencia.Text, out existencia);

    double.TryParse(txtcantidadvendida.Text, out venta);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtexistencia.Text))
    {               
        double parseAux = 0.0;
        double.TryParse(txtexistencia.Text, out parseAux);
    }
    else
    {
        if (venta > existencia)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("La cantidad que quiere vender es mayor que la cantidad disponible actualmente para la venta de este producto.");
            txtcodigo.Clear();
            txtdescripcion.Clear();
            txtreferencia.Clear();
            txtmarca.Clear();
            txtexistencia.Clear();
            txtcantidadvendida.Clear();
            txtpreciopieza.Clear();
            txttotalventa.Clear();
            txtcodigo.Enabled = false;
            btnbuscar.Enabled = false;
            txtcantidadvendida.Enabled = false;
            btnañadir.Enabled = false;
            btneliminar.Enabled = false;
            btnventa.Enabled = false;
            txtcodigo.Enabled = true;
            btnbuscar.Enabled = true;
            txtcodigo.Select();
        }
        else
        {
            Double a = 0;
            a = Double.Parse(txtcantidadvendida.Text) * Double.Parse(txtpreciopieza.Text);
            txttotalventa.Text = a.ToString();
            txtcantidadvendida.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: captura la exception en tu codigo. Con eso sabras que es lo que pasa.

Comment: Samuel, si explicas un poco que quieres lograr con el programa quiza podamos ayudarte mejor. Puedes ver este enlace como referencia https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Pon un punto de interrupcion (breakpoint) en la primera línea de tu método y depura paso a paso lo que pasa.

Comment: @ctm002 eso serviria si este diera error pero no me da error.

Comment: @Kenny que me valide los datos que ingreso en un cuadro de texto si mi busqueda me llena el campo existencia(txtexitencia) me compare con el campo venta(txtcantidadvendida) si venta > existencia que me dispare un error sino que continue.

Comment: @Pikoh no se como se hace un punto de interrupcion, si me puedes ofrecer un video o un libro donde me explice como hacerlo te lo agradeceria que segun veo se ha de utilizar mucho.

Comment: En la ventana de codigo,si pulsas en el borde izquierdo verás que aparece un circulo rojo. Eso es un breakpoint. Si ahora ejecutas el código,cuando el flujo llegue a ese punto la ejecución se detendrá. A partir de ahi,cada vez que pulses F10 se ejecutará una linea,y asi vas viendo por donde pasa. Además,poniendo el cursor encima de cualquier variable veras su valor.

Comment: Esto es un resumen,pero es muy importante aprender a depurar bien.

Comment: gracias @Pikoh tratare de hacerlo y mas adelante tratare de explicar mejor mi error

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que ni hace nada ni da error porque, según tu código, si el TextBox `txtexistencia` tiene algún contenido no hace nada:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtexistencia.Text))
{               
    double parseAux = 0.0;
    double.TryParse(txtexistencia.Text, out parseAux);
}
```

Según este código, si `txtexistencia` tiene algún contenido (no es nulo ni vacío) intenta parsear el contenido a `double` y almacenarlo en `parseAux` pero después no se hace nada más.